# Adding mask and thousand delimeter to EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I need to put currency at the start of text and this text should be divide thousands by dots. Now I am using `MaskedTextChangedListener` from [this](https://github.com/RedMadRobot/input-mask-android) library, so my code is following:

```
val listener = MaskedTextChangedListener(
            "[000].[000].[000]",
            true,monthlyInstallment.editText!!, null,null)

    listener.rightToLeft = true

    monthlyInstallment.editText?.addTextChangedListener(listener)
```

Here you can see that I added mask and used `rightToLeft` value in order to divide amount by dots. The problem is that if I will put currency to the start of mask like `$[000].[000].[000]`, the currency appears only after I will fill all the mask, whereas I need to appear it when I will start typing.

Also I tried to put logic for adding currency in other `TextChangeListener`. My code is following

```
if(!monthlyInstallment.editText?.text.toString().startsWith("$ ")){
                    monthlyInstallment.editText?.setText("$ " + monthlyInstallment.editText?.text.toString())
                    Logger.msg("check " + monthlyInstallment.editText?.text.toString().length)
                }
                monthlyInstallment.editText?.setSelection(monthlyInstallment.editText?.text.toString().length)
```

Here problem is that my cursor is set somewhere, but not at the end of text. By the way, this code is placed into `afterTextChangedListener` method.

So can someone help me with one of the problem?

Comment: Just an advice, if you want to change the text of EditText in afterTextChangedListener it's better to use Spannables instead of changing the text itself. This way it won't screw cursor's position.

Comment: @h4rd4r7c0r3, can you explain how I can use it

Comment: `EditText.getText()` return `Editable` which implements `Spannable`. You can getText and update the `Spannable` itself.